# Using HTTP GET for online news comments crawling with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-crawler, urllib

I am doing a simple crawling task for crawling news comments from yahoo news (http://news.yahoo.com/peter-kassig-mother-isis-twitter-133155662.html). 
And this is my code:

```
import urllib
url2 = 'http://news.yahoo.com/_xhr/contentcomments/get_comments/?content_id=f8bf9dc7-1692-3283-825e-2d506952f57b&_device=full&count=10&sortBy=highestRated&isNext=true&offset=20&pageNumber=2&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_view_others=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_mutecommenter=1&enable_collapsed_comment=1'
url1 = 'http://news.yahoo.com/_xhr/contentcomments/get_comments/?content_id=f8bf9dc7-1692-3283-825e-2d506952f57b&_device=full&count=10&sortBy=highestRated&isNext=true&offset=10&pageNumber=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_view_others=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_mutecommenter=1&enable_collapsed_comment=1'


url15 = 'http://news.yahoo.com/_xhr/contentcomments/get_comments/?content_id=f8bf9dc7-1692-3283-825e-2d506952f57b&_device=full&count=10&sortBy=highestRated&isNext=true&offset=10&pageNumber=15&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_view_others=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_mutecommenter=1&enable_collapsed_comment=1'
u1 = urllib.urlopen(url1)
u2 = urllib.urlopen(url2)

u15 = urllib.urlopen(url15)

data1 = u1.read()
data2 = u2.read()

data15 = u15.read()

# data15 is same with data2!!!
```

I knew the comments are given by using GET (from Google Web Dev. - Network Tab), which means that I can just use URLs for crawling the comments. 
There are only two differences (pageNumber and offset) among url1, url2, and url5.

Though url1 is for pageNumber=1 and url15 is for pageNumber=15, it's same data! 
I don't know the reason why.

This is my first naive web crawling task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: @alfasin Yeah.. I edited my post. url1 and url15 points same data... But I think the offset do some important roles....